# Exception thrown when 0x5E25E44B (ucrtbased.dll) in Lampenproblem.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation when reading at position 0xDDDDDDCD

Tags: c++, multithreading, stdvector, access-violation

I tried to create some threads in c++ and while running the program I got a Problem from Visual Studio: `Ausnahme ausgelöst bei 0x5E25E44B (ucrtbased.dll) in Lampenproblem.exe: 0xC0000005: Zugriffsverletzung beim Lesen an Position 0xDDDDDDCD.`

my code:

```
vector<unsigned long long> OptimierteForm1(unsigned long long n, unsigned long long maxK, unsigned long long testLampen, double wechselfaktorN)
{...}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long                  AnzThreads = 4; //(unsigned long long)thread::hardware_concurrency;     // soviele threads wie CPU-Kerne

    unsigned long long                  minN;
    unsigned long long                  maxN;
    unsigned long long                  delN;
    unsigned long long                  maxK;
    int                                 prüfart;
    double                              wechselfaktorN;
    double                              wechselfaktorK;

    while (true)
    {
        cin >> prüfart;

        unsigned long long testLampen;

        switch (prüfart)
        {
        case 0:
            return 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            ...
            break;
        case 2:
            ...
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "min n eingeben: ";
            cin >> minN;
            cout << "max n eingeben: ";
            cin >> maxN;
            cout << "max k eingeben: ";
            cin >> maxK;
            cout << "Anzahl der zu testenden Lampen eingeben: ";
            cin >> testLampen;
            cout << "wechselfaktor für n eingeben (empfohlen 2): ";
            cin >> wechselfaktorN;

            delN = maxN - minN;

            for (size_t i = minN; i <= maxN; i+=AnzThreads)
            {
                vector<thread>  vt;
                vector<vector<unsigned long long>> PositiveRunden;
                for (size_t j = 0; j < AnzThreads; j++)
                {
                    unsigned long long n = i + j;
//HERE COMES THE PROBLEM:
                    vt.push_back(thread([n, maxK, testLampen, wechselfaktorN, &PositiveRunden] {PositiveRunden.push_back(OptimierteForm1(n, maxK, testLampen, wechselfaktorN)); }));
                }
                for (auto& j : vt)
                {
                    j.join();
                }
                cout << VectorenZuString(i, PositiveRunden);
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            ...
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Fehlerhafte Eingabe!\n";
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

This problem occured at vt.push_back(...);

I tried to optimize the runtime by using threads, if sb chooses case 3.
n goes for minN to maxN everytime 4 calculations simultaneous, gives the output and goes for the next 4 inputs.

Comment: `std::vector::push_back` is not threadsafe.

Comment: You need to first resize the vector appropriately to fit all of the results before you create the threads. Then have each thread write only to the vector index assigned to it.